# Executing multiple queries in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

Is there a possibility to run many queries, that are not next to each other in the text editor in SSMS, at one time?

Assuming we have:

```
select * from tab1
select * from tab2
select * from tab3
```

the aim is to somehow mark only first and last selects and run them at the same time.

Comment: comment off the unwanted query and execute

Comment: in this simple example that would work, but in more complex cases commenting  out would be a pain..

Comment: I don't know how much pain it is to you to comments off a query hopefully [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/ssms-tricks?view=sql-server-ver15) will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server management you can just select the query you want to execute and press F5

EDIT: YOu can even select a part of a query to execute only that part.
Example: `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <your where>`
And you select just after the `<table>` then your query will be executed without the WHERE

[image]

EDIT:
ctrl + alt + your select
[image]

Comment: Yes, I know it.  I would like to know if there is a possibility to select many queries (or many parts of queries if you prefere) at one time.

Comment: Select multiple parts, not sure atm?

Comment: Sorry, that was shortcut. Just select multiple selects that are not next to each other.

Comment: Found it, ctrl + alt and then do you select. Nice, I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

You can comment / uncomment a query easily by [un]commenting multiline comment start line. The second query is commented

```
select * from tab1;
/*
select * from tab2;
--*/
select * from tab3;
```

now it's uncommented

```
select * from tab1;
--/*
select * from tab2;
--*/
select * from tab3;
```

Comment: But if I have like 15 selects and want to run let's say every second one then it is inefficient.

Comment: @I.P.  .. My guess navigating over 7+ result sets in the Result pane is much more difficult problem. Can you explain why you want some 10+ queries in the same file?